# After closing the program in my project got error "CannotUnloadAppDomainException" in C#

Tags: c#

This started when I created and use reporting (rdlc) in my project and now everytime i open the form with reporting it is still working finem the error will show when I close my application how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you running your Reporting in sandbox? if so are you releasing the sandboxed app domain?

Comment: @sa_ddam213, what do you mean by sandbox?, this is a Windows Forms Application Project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender,System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also work for me.

> reportviewer.Reset();